# Is it possible to bundle JCE policy files with java program

Tags: java, cryptography

I want AES with GCM mode with 256-bit key size. Currently, this causes:

`Error java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size`

[Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3864276/4490400), this is due to export restrictions on cryptography and I need to install `Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files` from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html). I think it's too much to ask the users of my app to modify their JRE just to run my app. Is it possible to bundle the cryptography extension policy files into my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this question very similar to yours [Using encryption that would need Java Policy Files in openjre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156522/using-encryption-that-would-need-java-policy-files-in-openjre)

But the accepted answer does not work for me. Try this one

```
Field gate = Class.forName("javax.crypto.JceSecurity").getDeclaredField("isRestricted");
gate.setAccessible(true);
gate.setBoolean(null, false);
Field allPerm = Class.forName("javax.crypto.CryptoAllPermission").getDeclaredField("INSTANCE");
allPerm.setAccessible(true);
Object accessAllAreasCard = allPerm.get(null);
final Constructor<?> constructor = Class.forName("javax.crypto.CryptoPermissions").getDeclaredConstructor();
constructor.setAccessible(true);
Object coll = constructor.newInstance();
Method addPerm = Class.forName("javax.crypto.CryptoPermissions").getDeclaredMethod("add", java.security.Permission.class);
addPerm.setAccessible(true);
addPerm.invoke(coll, accessAllAreasCard);
Field defaultPolicy = Class.forName("javax.crypto.JceSecurity").getDeclaredField("defaultPolicy");
defaultPolicy.setAccessible(true);
defaultPolicy.set(null, coll);
```

Compatibility

- JRE 7: OK
- JRE 8 u101: OK
- JRE 8 u112: FAIL `Can not set static final boolean field javax.crypto.JceSecurity.isRestricted to (boolean)false`

Comment: This works for me (now). I guess there's a risk that it breaks with newer Java versions, like you said?

Comment: Yes it is. You may want to send a compatibility list when you distribute the application